# Perfectly Straight Vertical/Horizontal Line When Pressing the Shift Key (C++ and Qt 5.8)

Tags: c++, qt

I am performing a task to implement a perfectly straight vertical/horizontal line when the shift key is pressed in a program called EasyPaint. I have no errors in my code, but unfortunately, it also has zero effect on the program itself. When I draw a line and press shift, it does absolutely nothing. The code below is my method shiftPressEvent and my other method isMod. I tried to do a calculation of degrees to try and specify when the line should snap to a vertical alignment or horizontal alignment, but obviously, it seems to not be doing its intended job. If another set of eyes could maybe analyze the code and see where the problem lies, I'd greatly appreciate it. Also, if any further information is needed, please comment below. I can easily post the entire class of LineInstrument, but it's a tad lengthy.

**Added Methods in LineInstrument.cpp Before Edits**

```
void LineInstrument::shiftPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea){
if (imageArea.isPaint())
{
    imageArea.setImage(mImageCopy);
    double Y = mStartPoint.y() - mEndPoint.y();
    double X = mStartPoint.x() - mEndPoint.x();

    radianAngle = atan2(Y, X);
    degreeAngle = radianAngle * 180 / atan(1) * 4;

    if (isMod(event->key()))
    {
        if (abs(degreeAngle) >= 45 && abs(degreeAngle) <= 135)
        {
            mEndPoint.setX(mStartPoint.x());
        }

        else if (abs(degreeAngle) < 45 && abs(degreeAngle) > 135)
        {
            mEndPoint.setY(mStartPoint.y());
        }

        imageArea.update();
    }
}
}

bool LineInstrument::isMod(int key){
if (key == Qt::Key_Shift)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

**Added Methods in LineInstrument.cpp After Edits**

```
    void LineInstrument::shiftPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea)
{
    if (imageArea.isPaint())
    {
        imageArea.setImage(mImageCopy);
        double Y = mStartPoint.y() - mEndPoint.y();
        double X = mStartPoint.x() - mEndPoint.x();

        if (isMod(event->key()) && fabs(X) > fabs(Y))
        {
            mEndPoint.setY(mStartPoint.y());
            paint(imageArea, false);
        }

        else if (isMod(event->key()) && fabs(Y) >= fabs(X))
        {
            mEndPoint.setX(mStartPoint.x());
            paint(imageArea, false);
        }

    }
}

    bool LineInstrument::isMod(int key)

{
    if (key == Qt::Key_Shift)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**LineInstrument Header File Before Edits**

```
#ifndef LINEINSTRUMENT_H
#define LINEINSTRUMENT_H

#include "abstractinstrument.h"

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QKeyEvent>

/**
 * @brief Line instrument class.
 *
 */
class LineInstrument : public AbstractInstrument
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LineInstrument(QObject *parent = 0);

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    void shiftPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    bool isMod(int key);
protected:
    void paint(ImageArea &imageArea, bool isSecondaryColor = false, bool additionalFlag = false);

private:
    double radianAngle;
    double degreeAngle;
};

#endif // LINEINSTRUMENT_H
```

**LineInstrument Header File After Edits**

```
    #ifndef LINEINSTRUMENT_H
#define LINEINSTRUMENT_H

#include "abstractinstrument.h"

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QKeyEvent>

/**
 * @brief Line instrument class.
 *
 */
class LineInstrument : public AbstractInstrument
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LineInstrument(QObject *parent = 0);

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    void shiftPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event, ImageArea &imageArea);
    bool isMod(int key);
protected:
    void paint(ImageArea &imageArea, bool isSecondaryColor = false, bool additionalFlag = false);
};

#endif // LINEINSTRUMENT_H
```

Comment: Are you sure these methods are called? Also what element are you painting?

Comment: What class inherits imageArea?

Comment: @eyllanesc I believe that the class that inherits imageArea is QWidget. Also, I performed "View Call Hierarchy" on all the methods in LineInstrument and really none of them are called anywhere, yet they work within the EasyPaint program, so I assumed my method wouldn't have to be called anywhere either. The only method even used anywhere is the constructor.

Comment: If it is a widget it should only be painted inside paintEvent, do not assume things, you must be sure of things.

Comment: @eyllanesc Hmm... I'm mistaken. imageArea is inherited from the base class QWidget. As I am still fairly green to C++, how does this affect the code above?

Comment: I recommend learning C ++ before wanting to learn Qt. :P

Comment: Where did you find that you must create the shiftPressEvent method?

Comment: I wish it were that easy for me in my current curriculum lol. I didn't find it anywhere that I NEEDED to create the method. Originally I had it in the paint method for LineInstrument and I got rid of all errors, but wasn't getting any impact, so I tried this. Also, I did it so I could better access the shift key through a different set of parameters.

Comment: Share your code through github or gist to help you, in my possible answer I will explain the proper procedure.

Comment: Just share the entire repository to github? And also, I added a few more methods contained within LineInstrument. May or may not help.

Comment: Trying to share it as best as I can but it's a program with 100+ files. Github won't take it.

Comment: Then create a minimum project that reproduces the error. :P

Comment: If you want us to help you then you must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually, thankfully enough, I found the program already uploaded to github by the original creator. It's literally the program below with my two methods added on. https://github.com/Gr1N/EasyPaint

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you aren't calculating the angle in degrees properly. This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
degreeAngle = radianAngle * 180 / atan(1) * 4;
```

That's the same as:

```
degreeAngle = 4 * radianAngle * 180 / atan(1);
```

What you should do is create a proper named constant for pi by doing something like this:

```
const double kPi = atan(1.0) * 4.0;
```

And you should probably create a function to convert radians to degrees like this:

```
double toDegrees(double radians)
{
    return radians * 180.0 / kPi;
}
```

You can also figure out whether you want horizontal or vertical snapping much more easily by simply comparing the x delta and the y delta. If `X` is greater than `Y`, then you want a horizontal line, otherwise you want a vertical one. Something like this should do the trick:

```
if (fabs(X) > fabs(Y))
{
    mEndPoint.setY(mStartPoint.y());
}
else
{
    mEndPoint.setX(mStartPoint.x());
}
```

Now whether this will fix your problem or not depends on how your drawing actually happens.

Comment: Hmm... I took your advice to heart and got rid of everything to do with degrees/radians and simply compared the x and y deltas. Unfortunately, there's still no impact.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see why it's not drawing as you expect? I recommend putting a breakpoint in the `shiftPressEvent()` method to see if it's executing the way you think it is. What happens to `mEndPoint` in that function? Then, I would put a breakpoint in the `paint()` method and see what `mEndPoint` looks like there. Do they match? Did the line get drawn correctly?